# Automatically delete entries missing from import with Solspace Importer?

Tags: solspace-importer

I have a client who will be maintaining a phone directory on their site, updating it on a roughly monthly basis. The import will be a CSV file, and my plan is to use Solspace Importer to turn the data into channel entries.

What I'm wondering is: is there a way to automatically remove entries if they don't exist in a newer import (for example, an employee has left the company and so isn't in the new CSV file).

I found a similar discussion here:
[Delete records that were not updated](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/delete-records-that-were-not-updated)

...but since this directory data won't be be imported on exact intervals, something automated/scheduled with cron won't work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Importer has the ability to delete an entry when a match is found (using the duplicate entry detection feature), but unfortunately it's not possible to delete entries where a match *wasn't* found. What would therefore need to be done is delete (or close, or expire) entries before importing new ones. Unfortunately Importer doesn't have a feature to clear channels of entries before imports. You would have to do this manually before running the import.

I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions